# Module works with Cabal but not with Stack

Tags: haskell, cabal, haskell-stack, sbv

I'm trying to install the `sbv` module https://hackage.haskell.org/package/sbv

Installation with Stack works great (no errors):

```sh
stack install sbv
```

but then I cannot import the corresponding module in `stack ghci`:

```hs
import Data.SBV

-- <no location info>: error:
--     Could not find module ‘Data.SBV’
--     Perhaps you meant Data.Set (from containers-0.6.2.1)
```

Now, when I try with Cabal instead:

```sh
cabal new-install sbv --lib
```

Everything runs smoothly on `ghci`

```hs
import Data.SBV
prove $ \x -> x `shiftL` 2 .== 4 * (x::SWord8)

--- Q.E.D.      (<-- this is the expected output)
```

However, still no luck with `stack ghci` (same error as before). This is the case whether `stack install sbv` was done globally or in the context of a Stack project.

Is there a way to make `sbv` work with the Stack installation (even if it was installed via cabal)?

Comment: You can specify the package when starting GHCi using `stack ghci --package sbv`, or use `:set -package sbv` within GHCi to make an installed package visible, although note that changing the package flags will reset your session. If you have several dependencies like this, it becomes much easier to list them in a project file so they’re available automatically.

Comment: for a stack project, is there any difference between using a `.cabal` file, as @leftaroundabout suggested, or a `stack.yaml` file to mention dependencies?

Comment: @Jivan they are complementary. Essentially, the `.cabal` or `package.yaml` file specifies the direct dependencies of your own project without worrying about which particular versions of libraries actually work together, whereas `stack.yaml` specifies one concrete configuration that's known to work and where to get the packages from. In principle the `.cabal` file is enough, but `stack.yaml` can make your project more portable and future proof.

Comment: Maybe it is good time to switch to nix;) Following one-liner is working for my ghci: `nix-shell -p "haskell.packages.ghc8106.ghcWithPackages (p: [p.sbv])"` then run ghci and import Data.SBV...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Stack has always eschewed the idea of *manually installing libraries* that could then be imported in files on that computer. (Cabal has more recently gone away from that too.) And there are very good reasons for this: relying on “at some point I typed this command” quickly leads to maintenance issues and duplicate work figuring out the dependencies again as soon as you try to run your code on another machine.

Thus, the recommended way is to *always mention dependencies right where they're needed*. For anything serious, you would use a `.cabal` (or hpack) file in your project; for smaller one-file stuff you can just make them [Stack scripts](https://wespiser.com/posts/2020-02-02-Command-Line-Haskell.html).

If you don't have any files at all then... well, first, you may want to consider getting a file *now*... but you can also use the the [Stack global project](https://docs.haskellstack.org/en/stable/yaml_configuration/), which is what `stack ghci` will by defaul use.

Finally, you can also just mention the dependency right at the command line: `stack ghci --package sbv`.
I don't really recommend this, unless you're really just quickly trying out something.

Comment: Your last suggestion worked well, namely `stack ghci --package sbv` — any place you could point to with explanations about how to go with the "correct" manner?

Comment: This introduction looks easy: https://haskell-at-work.com/episodes/2018-05-13-introduction-to-cabal.html